# Unable to test the error messages in my webpage

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web page with multiple fields. In there i have few mandatory fields if i enter update button without entering a mandatory field it has to show an error. So now i want to test that whether particular error message is coming or not and then i have to test remaining fields also.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class TestProfileCompanyDetailsPage 
{
    WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void verifyProfileCompanyDetailsPage() throws Exception
    {
        driver = DriverInIt.getInstance().getDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        LoginIntoVendors login=PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginIntoVendors.class);

        login.verifyLoginVendors();

        VendorsHomePageApp vhpapp=PageFactory.initElements(driver, VendorsHomePageApp.class);

        vhpapp.clickOnProfileTab();

        ProfileCompanyDetailsPage proCompDetPage=PageFactory.initElements(driver, ProfileCompanyDetailsPage.class);

        proCompDetPage.clickOnCompDetEdit();

        proCompDetPage.clickAndEnterCompName("IBM");

        proCompDetPage.clickOnUpdateButton();

       }

    public boolean IsTestElementPresent(WebDriver driver)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/section/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/p[2]/span"));
            return true;
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }



}
```

**Here is the Page :**

[image]

**HTML code:**

```
<p class="mB10px" style="padding-left: 20%;">
<button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 120px;" ng-click="saveVendor(1)" ng-class="{"cbc-btn-spin":persist==1}">Update</button>
<span class="btn-link mL5px vBot pointer" ng-click="cancelVendor(1)">Cancel</span>
</p>
<p class="mB10px show" ng-class="{"show":uiVendorError1.length>0}" style="display: none; padding-left: 20%;">
<span class="error ng-binding" ng-bind="uiVendorError1">Please enter Company Description</span>
</p>
<p class="mB10px" ng-class="{"show":uiVendorSuccess1.length>0}" style="display: none; padding-left: 20%;">
<span class="greenC ng-binding" ng-bind="uiVendorSuccess1"/>
</p>
```

Comment: So what is the problem with that?? is there any exception?? and need to share HTML code for error message portion as well

Comment: No Exception, I have company name and description fields i want test both fields error messages after clicking on update button. Above code is for only once i should stop this test case here but i need to continue test.

Comment: Is there any other ways to test those portions.

Comment: @sandeepkumar - html code for the error msg please

Comment: @nullpointer - Yeah attached.

Answer (score 2):

```
// do stuff to cause the error message to show up
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Please enter Company Description']")).isDisplayed());
```

In the above if the error message isn't there it'll throw an exception. This isn't very good, however, since the error might take a moment to pop up after validation and your test may have already tested to see if it's there. A better solution would be to use a web driver wait and check that it becomes visible in the expected time period. Also, please note that if the error message has an ID it is much better to select on that than using the text matching XPath. Better example:

```
// do stuff to cause the error message to show up
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[text()='Please enter Company Description']")));
```

This will wait until the error message is visible (the element returns `true` for it's `isDisplayed` method). If it doesn't become visible within `10` seconds then a `TimeoutException` will be thrown. Note that this is just an example of how to check for the element, it is usually best practice in a test to catch that exception and have an assertion failure with a better, more descriptive, error message.

To check multiple fields, just make that a helper method that you call with assorted Strings you expect them to match and use a variable rather than hard coding the text that should be matched. Also be careful if the text has any quotes (single or double) as that can result in invalid XPath.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until your element has some text with custom `ExpectedConditions` as below :-

```
public boolean IsTestElementPresent(WebDriver driver)
{
    try
    {
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

       return wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                        WebElement el = d.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.error.ng-binding"));
                        return (el.getText().length() > 0);
                    }
                });
    }catch(TimeoutExceptione e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Edited** :- And if you want to get element with contains error meassage, try as below :-

```
public boolean IsTestElementPresent(WebDriver driver)
{
    try
    {
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(., 'Please enter Company Description')]")));

       return true;

    }catch(TimeoutExceptione e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Lets say this one is for "Company name" field fine, i need to continue test mean to test "Description" field. Hope you understand.